# SQL Server: join If

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the below table. I need to create a join where ownername is captured first and if null use secondaryname

```
from table A
 left join HR on a.ownername = hr.id
--or a.secondaryname = hr.id  this does not work
and hr.active = y
```

Table A

```
 ID     SecondaryName    OwnerName    
 1        jaj              null         
 2        jat              jat
 3        joa              nel
```

Table HR Table

```
 Role            ID     Active
 Senior          jat     Y
 Senior          nel     Y
 Specialist      jaj     Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE`

```
left join HR on COALESCE(a.OwnerName, a.SecondaryName) = hr.id
```